# Use jsmediatags with Angular 4

Tags: angular

I've been trying to use jsmediatags library with Angular 4, but couldn't get it to work. I have followed tutorials on using an external script with Angular 2+ - still no luck. I get the following error: `{type: "fileReader", info: "Offset 0 hasn't been loaded yet."}` Any idea to make this work?

I'm using angular 4.3.6

Here is the code:

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "jsmediatags": "^3.8.0",
...

},
...
```

test.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
declare var jsmediatags: any;
import * as jsmediatags from "jsmediatags";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-tests',
    templateUrl: './tests.component.html',
})
export class TestsComponent implements{
    getMeta(event) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        console.log(file);
        jsmediatags.read(file, {
            onSuccess: tag => {
                alert('success');
                console.log(tag);
            },
            onError: error => {
                alert('error');
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

tests.component.html

```
<input (change)="getMeta($event)" type="file">
```

Comment: Give some code please...

Comment: @Dr.Geek I added the code.